# Is it possible to make the "-s" an automatic option on grep?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm using [Mac OS X v10.9.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks). Occasionally in my terminal, I will run grep commands like:

```
grep -i -s 'mystring' *
```

Is there a way I can make the "-s" (--no-messages) option the default whenever I run grep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up an alias to replace `grep` with `grep -s`. This would be in somewhere like ~/.bashrc in the form `alias grep='grep -s'`.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.bashrc file, but I do have a ~/.profile file.  However adding the line "alias grep=grep -s" resulted in a "-bash: alias: -s: not found" error when I exited and re-entered my terminal.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the quotes above. (Should be `alias grep='grep -s'`)

Comment: Thanks, I put that in, restarted my terminal, but running a command like "find ~/workspace/myproject/ -name "*" | xargs grep 'mytoken'" still results in "grep: /Users/davea/workspace/myproject/subdir/: Is a directory" messages.  (If I manually add the "-s" to the command those messages go away.)

Comment: Don't use xargs. It works for me anyway

Comment: When I remove xargs those messages go away.